# Is there a way for turbolinks to run within rspec/Capybara?

Tags: rspec, capybara, turbolinks

I came across an issue where I need to compensate for show being called twice due to Turbolinks. I want to be able to catch this and similar issues in my testing, but since this issue isn't reproducible in a test, I assume that Turbolinks isn't enabled by default. Can someone confirm whether this is true and share info on whether it's possible to enable it?

Answer (score 1):

Turbolinks requires JavaScript, which isn't supported by the default Capybara browser (`rack_test`). But you can set up an alternative web browser, and mark your tests that require JavaScript by passing `js: true`:

```
describe "My feature"
  it "Can test the front page without JavaScript" do
    # Non-JS test here
  end

  it "Tests a JS-requiring feature", js: true do
    # JS tests here
  end
end
```

Capybara will then use the driver configured in `Capybara:javascript_driver` to run that test. By default, this is Selenium, but you may like to look at [Capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) as an alternative that (might) be easier to set up.

The [Capybara documentation has more details about alternative JavaScript-supporting drivers](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara#Drivers).

Comment: I'm using selenium-webdriver and I had already tried that, but just set it up again with js: true.  The setup of my site is that there are links to the show pages of a certain type of model from the main homepage.  I put a print statement at the very beginning of the show method for that model's controller and when I click the link myself, I see two calls to show.  But when I run the spec and it clicks the link, there's only one call to show.  So I assume this means that turbolinks is not running?

Comment: you can also define this at the service level

Answer (score 0):

Turbolinks 5 beta doesn't currently evaluate inline javascript, but will with the 5.0 release. I'm not sure if your code is inline or not. Other than that, there is nothing specific that I know of that should prevent Capybara from working with turbolinks.